# Efficient method to update Map values

Tags: java, optimization, collections

We have an array with transaction details of more than ten million records

```
Key1    Key2    Value
-----------------------
A       B       <value>
B       C       <value>
D       A       <value>
...
...
```

The requirement is to perform basic arithmetic operation(add/subtract) on "value" from Key1 and add resulting value to Key2 (in a single transaction) for each of the records. The order of the transactions should be maintained. 
The resulting map should have the cumulative transaction values.

```
Key     Result
A       <result>
B       <result>
C       <result>
...
...
```

Please suggest an efficient solution to this scenario.

### Edit

Apologies for not making this clear in the question earlier.

```
Sample data:
------------

Row1 -> A,B,Add,10.0
Row2 -> C,D,Subtract,20.0
Row3 -> D,B,Add,50.0
Row4 -> B,X,Subtract,30.0

Initial Map:
------------
A     1000
B     1000
C     1000
D     1000
X     1000

Row 1 => 10.0 to be subtracted from B and added to A (B:990 - A:1010)
Row 2 => 20.0 to be subtracted from C and added to D (C:980 - D:1020)
Row 3 => 50.0 to be subtracted from B and added to D (B:940 - D:1070)
Row 4 => 30.0 to be subtracted from B and added to X (B:910 - X:1030)

Resulting Map:
--------------
A    1010
B     910
C     980
D    1070
X    1030
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a list of transaction. Let's represent one transaction with its own class called

```
public class Transaction {

    private String target;
    private String source;
    private String operation;
    private int amount;

    public Transaction(String target, String source, String operation, int amount) {
        this.target = target;
        this.source = source;
        this.operation = operation;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    // + getters

}
```

`source` will represent the source of the transaction and `target` the target. In the case of an `"Add"` operation, the source will be deduced by the `amount` and the target will be increased by the amount. If the operation is `"Subtract"`, the transaction is reversed.

Then, given a `Map<String, Integer> map` that holds the initial values, we can loop over those transactions and make the calculation. During each one, we just need to subtract the amount from the source and add it to the target (in the case of an `"Subtract"`, the amount is negative so the transaction is effectively reversed).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // set-up sample data
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String s : Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "X")) {
        map.put(s, 1000);
    }
    List<Transaction> transactions = Arrays.asList(
        new Transaction("A","B","Add",10),
        new Transaction("C","D","Subtract",20),
        new Transaction("D","B","Add",50),
        new Transaction("B","X","Subtract",30)
    );

    // implement the transactions
    for (Transaction t : transactions) {
        final int amount = t.getOperation().equals("Add") ? t.getAmount() : -t.getAmount();
        map.put(t.getSource(), map.get(t.getSource()) - amount);
        map.put(t.getTarget(), map.get(t.getTarget()) + amount);
    }

    System.out.println(map); // prints "{A=1010, B=910, C=980, D=1070, X=1030}"
}
```

Comment: thank you. I will run some tests with large data set, but this solution is helpful. I was wondering if there is a possibility to improve the performance by processing the 'transactions' in chunks in a multi-threaded fashion (ignoring the original map value, but adding the value at the end of all transactions). I will explore this further. thanks again

Comment: Have n threads work on n ranges of this list(concurrent version). If you need even more speed, you can use a gpgpu api.

Answer (score 0):

```
// map1 and map2 are your two existing maps
Map<Key, Value> resultMap = new Map<Key, Value>();

for (Map.Entry<Key, Value> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
    resultMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() + map2.get(entry.getKey()));
}
```

Comment: Since the input consists of 3 values (`Key1`, `Key2`, and `Value`), this answer seems lacking.

Comment: I understand the question to be the key-wise addition of the two maps. Perhaps I misunderstand?

Comment: Your `map1` only has `Key` and `Value`, so you are always doing `result[Key] = result[Key] + Value` when OP wants `result[Key2] = result[Key1] + Value`. Also, your `resultMap` is initially empty, so you *will* get `NullPointerException` with that code.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I see your two maps now, but that still won't work, because the first two sample lines in the question are `B = A + value` and `C = B + value`, meaning that the second `B` is the result of the first one, otherwise the statement *"The order of the transactions should be maintained"* does not make any sense.

Comment: Please explain what this code does and how it answers the question.